# Jest + React: it.each() await for variable

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch, each

**i have this code in a jest file with react:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import HomePage from '../../pages/HomePage';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

jest.setTimeout(15000);
global.IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT = true;

describe('test table files', () => {
  let list;
  let allData;
  let store = mockStore({});
  let container = document.createElement('div');
  
  beforeEach((done) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5050/files/data')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((dat) => {
        allData = dat;
        fetch('http://localhost:5050/files/list')
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((fil) => {
            list = fil.files;
            done();
          });
      });

    const allReducers = {
      files: {
        list,
        allData,
      },
    };
    store = mockStore(allReducers);
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);
  });
  
  afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    container = null;
  });
  
  it.each(allData)('testing $file', async ({ file, lines }) => {
    console.log('file', file);
    act(() => {
      ReactDOM.createRoot(container).render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <HomePage />
        </Provider>
      );
    });
    expect(lines).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
  
});
```

i ran jest and the variable `allData` is *undefined*
i need to run one test for every children in `allData` *Array*

> the `allData` is fetched from api

please help me to find a solution without any external library
keep in mind that i need wait for `allData` is fetched from a external api

Answer (score 0):

**i solve this, if you need the solution is decribed below**

first i create a `jest.config.js` file
**with content:**

```js
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args));

module.exports = async () => {
  const allData = await (await fetch('http://localhost:5050/files/data')).json();
  const fileList = (await (await fetch('http://localhost:5050/files/list')).json()).files;
    
  return {
    setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    resetMocks: true,
    globals: {
      allData,
      fileList,
    },
  };
};
```

Store the fetched `allData` and the `fileList` data in global

i can read late, next create a `jest.setup.js` file
**with content:**

> require('whatwg-fetch');

only for the fetch error in your components
i'ts all, now you can access to the fetched data typing `global.allData` or `global.fileList`
or any variable you define with

> global.`you_variable_defined` in **jest.config.js** globals section

in you test files
**example:**

```js
describe('test table files', () => {
  it.each(global.allData)('testing $file', async ({ file, lines }) => {
    act(() => {
      ReactDOM.createRoot(container).render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <HomePage />
        </Provider>
      );
    });

    // expect(lines).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
}
```